# Unable to resolve a type in Integration Testing using WebApplicationFactory

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-3.1

This is the problem I have: `InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'WebApi.Test.Repository.TestRepository' while attempting to activate 'WebApi.Test.Services.TestService'.`

Of course, the problem is, It seems I cant construct a `TestRepository`, when the service needs it.

This is the Repo:

```
public class TestRepository : GenericRepository<TestEntity>
{
    public TestRepository(TestContext dbContext
        , ILoggerFactory loggerFactory) : base(dbContext, loggerFactory)
    {
    }
}
```

The service basically has a `TestRepository` as a parameter in its constructor (but the issue seems to be before that).

This is my custom `WebApplicationFactory`

```
public class ApiWebApplicationFactory : WebApplicationFactory<Startup>
    {
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; private set; }

        protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration(config =>
            {
                Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                    .Build();

                config.AddConfiguration(Configuration);
            });


            //Add Services
            builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
            {
                // Add framework services.
                services.AddMvc();

                //Add ApplicationDbContext using an in-memory database for testing.
                services.AddDbContext<TestContext>(options =>
                    options.UseInMemoryDatabase("InMemoryDbForTesting"));

                services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));

                // Build the service provider.
                var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

                // Create a scope to obtain a reference to the database
                // context (ApplicationDbContext).
                using var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope();

                var db = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<TestContext>();

                // Ensure the database is created.
                db.Database.EnsureCreated();

                // Seed the database with test data.
                InitializeTestDatabase(db);

                
                services.AddScoped<GenericRepository<TestEntity>, TestRepository>();
                services.AddScoped<GenericService<TestEntity, TestRequest, TestResponse>, TestService>();
                services.AddScoped<GenericController<TestEntity, TestRequest, TestResponse>, TestController>();
            });
        }

        private void InitializeTestDatabase(TestContext textContext)
        {
            textContext.TestEntities.Add(new TestEntity { Id = 1 });
        }
    }
```

All the Generic classes are abstract classes. This is the `GenericRepository`:

```
public abstract class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T>
        where T : BaseEntity
    {
        protected DbContext _context;
        private DbSet<T> _table;
        private ILogger _logger;

        public GenericRepository(DbContext context
            , ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            _context = context;
            _table = context.Set<T>();
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<GenericRepository<T>>();
        } 

         //CRUD Methods
    }
```

I was thinking if it is because Im not creating the ILoggerFactory on my Custom WebAppFactory, if that is the case, how can someone create an ILoggerFactory?.

What I tried:
I tried to add the following line:

```
services.AddScoped<DbContext, TestContext>();
```

but I keep getting the same error.

This is the Service:

```
public abstract class GenericService<T, Request, Response>
    where T : BaseEntity
    where Response : class, IResponseDto
    where Request : class, IRequestDto
{
    protected readonly GenericRepository<T> _genericRepository;
    protected readonly IMapper _mapper;
    protected readonly ILogger _logger;
    public GenericService(GenericRepository<T> genericRepository
        , IMapper mapper
        , ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        _genericRepository = genericRepository;
        _mapper = mapper;
        _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<GenericService<T, Request, Response>>();
    }

    //Methods
}
```

Comment: Do you realize that the"generic" service and "generic" repository do nothing except alias `DbContext` methods without offering anything? A DbSet is already a Repository, a DbContext is already a Unit-of-Work. Something with `CRUD` methods isn't even a repository, it's a class with some functions. It doesn't abstract database access, that's what the EF Core providers do.

Comment: The `TestService` class is missing but I suspect its constructor accepts a `TestRepository` , not the registered `GenericRepository<TestEntity>`. There's no inheritance relation between a generic type and a concrete type. There's no inheritance relation between `List<T>` and `List<int>`.

Comment: `services.AddDbContext<TestContext>(options => options.UseInMemoryDatabase("InMemoryDbForTesting"));` you already use the in-memory repo. What's the point of the TestRepository then? Is it only needed because the *non*generic "GenericRepository" only uses a single entity as a generic parameter instead of the multi-entity DbContext?

Comment: I see you already run into trouble with those "generic" repositories and services. You can't make a simple tweak to fix the non-generic "generic" repository **anti**pattern. A DbContext is already a multi-entity Unit-of-Work. The DbSet is the Repository. You're trying to shove the multi-entity UoW inside a single-entity Repo class. There's simply *no* reason or benefit in using such a design. This isn't a "best practice", on the contrary it's a well know *bad* practice. DI fails because it's meant to work with concrete types, and yet the repo expects an undefined `DbContext`

Comment: In fact, what you posted fails for the exact same reason your previous question fails - you can't inject DbContext. To make DI resolve this you'd need to change the GenericRepo to `GenericRepo<TContext,TEntity> where TContext:DbContext` and accept the `TContext` in the constructor. Again and again, what's the point? All this code only adds complexity for absolutely *no* benefit. The problems though are numerous. Your `Update` will also persist 42 DELETEs you didn't realize were pending. UoW will be broken if you call `SaveChanges` in every `CUD` operation.

Comment: DbContext already allows logging, auditing and interception, so you're *double logging* the operations at best. To load related entities you'll have to either use `Include` in the "generic" repo or load them separately, possibly using N+1 queries instead of just 1 to load N related entities.